# Add minutes to string hh:mm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is in hh:mm (17:30) and a duration in minutes (example 120 mins). How can I add the 120 minutes to the 17:30 string to come up with 17:30 + 120 minutes.

Comment: More importantly, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: What you've posted isn't a question.

Comment: I apologize. I'm asking for suggestions on how to accomplish this. I haven't found a good starting place as the starting date is just a text string.

Comment: heres a good resource to get you into JS date and time functions http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm 
If you can't work it out, Improve your question with examples of what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [phpjs](http://phpjs.org), I can get it to work by using:

```
var a = strtotime('+120 minutes', strtotime('2000-01-01 15:30:00'))
var b = date('H:i', a)
alert(b); // '17:30'
```

Or, if you prefer, try http://www.datejs.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

I had same kinda issue, used below code. One can use same code to update hours too as well as minutes.

```
var timeValue = ("23:59").split(":")
var minuteAddValue = Number(timeValue[1]) + 1
var date = new Date(null,null,null,timeValue[0],minuteAddValue);
var minuteValue = date.getMinutes();
minuteValue = minuteValue.length == 1 ? ("0" + minuteValue) : minuteValue
var hourValue = date.getHours();
var updatedTime = minuteValue+":"+hourValue 

//output - "00:00"
```